# How do I convert OSM XML to rendered tiles for offline use?

Tags: openstreetmap, windows

I'm new to OpenStreetMap and I'm trying to figure out how to process an OSM XML file and create map tiles for offline use. I already have the OSM XML file downloaded; I just don't know what to do next.

Once I have the tiles, I'll be displaying them in a control hosted in a Windows application. The basic application is complete. I'm now moving the data to local storage instead of online.

How do I take my OSM XML and process it into tiles?

Comment: I see that you have already prepared to use tiles. However, this may still be interesting reading http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/. Rendering from vectors on-demand is much more flexible than using tiles and your users could fine-tune the styles easily.

Comment: QGIS does the rendering in the RAM, so you might run out of that on larger areas. This will result in painfully slow rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a renderer like Maperitive, Mapnik or Tilemill to create the tiles.

Since you are new to the subject, I suggest to install Maperitive, and try a small area first.

Comment: I found Maperitive on my own late Friday night and gave it a shot. It works and is simple to use. It's currently processing a data file and has been generating tiles since Saturday afternoon. I can see it's making progress but I wonder if there is a better (faster) way to generate the tiles. Currently processing about 80 tiles per second.

Comment: With Mapnik you can use multiple CPU cores (if you have). But you need to set up a PostgreSQL database for it. That is a bit of extra work in advance to get the tiles faster (once it is working).